# Python: how to change unicode to string

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried to upload csv files in colab, but I failed to change filen name as string format.

help me please

Here's the code:

```
uploaded = files.upload()

files_name = np.zeros(10).astype(np.string_)

for i, name in enumerate(uploaded.keys()):
    print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=name, length=len(uploaded[name])))

    file_names[i] = name

data = pd.read_csv(file_name[0])
```

Comment: Is it a bytes type and you want it as a string type? Or are dealing in Python 2? Bytes to string: `name.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code, first is the **variable name**. You should check all the variables' name to avoid the undefined errors.

Another one is the **decoding problem**. The result in you `files_name` is encode in to bytes. Therefore, you should decode when you read in.

```py
data = pd.read_csv(files_name[0].decode("utf8"))
```